# sorting in Excel with Rank Function in Group

Tags: excel, sorting, unique, rank

[image: case rank ascending]
hi, I would like to discuss on how to get sorting ascending formula from this case. Expected result is as shown in the picture in blue column. The only reference that can be used is Rank column (Yellow) and Group column (white).

Any idea how to get the rank unique expected column (blue)? the flow is go through in the group, find the min number in the rank within the group and put into the reverse order.

Comment: Can you tell more about why your expected ranks include a 10, 9 8 and 7 and so on? There is not much to go by and your own attempt is missing as well.

Comment: Also, why is you unique range not 3,2,1,7,6,5,4,10,9,8??

Comment: I want to make sort the rank with ascending per group.

Comment: I think you are right, the correct order is 3,2,1,7,6,5,4,10,9,8

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Group` is in A1, series fill ColumnC from `1` to `10` then sort that column from where the second Group starts (C4:C10) by A `A to Z` and B `Smallest to Largest`.

Comment: I want to make it automatic using excel formula. not using excel function